# Is it sensible to store long, unique text strings in OLAP cubes for drillthrough retrieval (especially in SSAS)?

Tags: ssas, olap, drillthrough

I'm motivated to store some long text strings in an OLAP cube, long on the order of 1,000s or 10,000s of characters -- but I'm wondering if this will lead me astray. (I'm also curious to learn a little more about how OLAP engines handle strings.) The particular use case I have in mind is that I have a unique, pre-existing "record description" for each of my OLAP facts, and I want to put those descriptions in the cube so that I have the option to get them back when I do a DRILLTHROUGH operation. In contrast, I don't need the record descriptions to appear when doing normal pivot table / aggregate type operations. (The descriptions are too long to display sensibly in a pivot table, plus each fact has a unique description, meaning it doesn't make sense to aggregate over descriptions.) My current dataset has around 700,000 facts, though I'm also curious if the answer would change for larger datasets.

My hope was that an OLAP server could do something sensible if I put these long strings in a cube. In the Sql Server / SSAS case in particular, I thought perhaps I'd put them in a dimension marked as ROLAP, to save memory usage, and use a degenerate dimension (aka a "fact dimension", in SSAS terminology), to avoid needless ETL complexities. But I'm curious if this would be regarded as a horrible practice for some reason, or if there are any hidden gotchas.

**Update**: My example use case is where you have a string associated with each OLAP fact. But it might also be instructive to consider the case where the strings are instead associated with each particular value of a particular dimension. (e.g. Suppose you had a Company dimension and each company had a somewhat lengthy Company Description string.)

Comment: I stumbled on this page and am compelled to mention (belatedlty!) that this is an incredibly bad idea. And that's an understatement.

Comment: @TomChester I appreciate (non-ironically) how emphatic your comment is, and you may well be right. If you wanted to add an answer briefly explaining WHY this is horrible, that would be even better!

Answer (score 3):

Here's what I've been able to uncover about the implications of storing such strings in SSAS, especially SSAS 2008. Where I consider data structures, it's exclusively focused on MOLAP storage, which is what I've been experimenting with.

First, standard MS ETL (extract/transform/load, i.e. data import) tools like Business Intelligence Development Studio may try to prevent you from importing large textfields, especially varchar(max) fields, but there is a workaround, and it's proven effective for me. (For BIDS it involves manually setting the DataSize element in an XML file, potentially to the magic size of 163315555 bytes. Props to [Matija](http://milambda.blogspot.com/2007/09/sql-server-2005-analysis-services.html) [Lah](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/298085/ssas-varchar-nvarchar-column-size-incorrectly-mapped-between-data-source-views-and-cube-dimensions) for figuring this out.)

Second, as far as I can tell, storing lots of long, unique strings shouldn't wreak havoc on the on-disk data structures used by SSAS. Also, the size of the string data on disk should be of the same order of magnitude as the string data in your data source. Here's some rough info on SSAS handles strings:

- The core OLAP data structures (e.g. for the attributes of a dimension, or for the facts of a measure groups) don't directly contain strings; instead contain offsets into "string store" files (extensions .ksstore, .asstore, .bsstore, or .string.data), which contain the actual string data.
- Within a given string store, each string is represented only once. If several rows in your source data tables contain duplicate strings, then at the SSAS/MOLAP level, that will translate into duplicated file-offsets, rather than duplicated string values
- If you're source string has length n, then the corresponding data structure in the string store has 8-ish bytes of overhead, plus 2*n bytes per character. (Strings are inherently stored in 2-byte Unicode format in SSAS.)
- For some fantastic detail about this stuff, I suggest the book [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Analysis Services Unleashed](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672330016), in particular chapter 20, "The Physical Data Model".
- At least in my experiments, string store files do not seem to be compressed -- at least they're not notably smaller than an uncompressed string store would be.

I've verified experimentally that text data takes the same order of magnitude of bytes whether stored in SSAS MOLAP or in a sql table. In particular, I did a "select sum(len(myfield)) from mytable" from one of my dimension tables, and then compared to the size of the corresponding attribute's files in my SSAS data directory. Size was 172MB in SQL and 304MB in SQL server. (Sql size was 147MB if I summed all *unique* strings, rather than all strings.) In my case the size difference was mostly explained by character encoding; my source sql data is stored with one byte per character, whereas SSAS stores all strings with two bytes per character. I found that the .kssstore file totally dominated all the other files associated with this attribute in size, regardless of whether or not I optimized the attribute via AttributeHierarchyOptimizedState=FullyOptimized.

Third, there is a 4GB cap on the size of string store files, which limits the amount of unique text that can be associated, say, with a particular dimension/attribute. In my case I'm less than 10% of the way to the limit, but this might affect some people. (Quick order-of-magnitude calculation for the original post: 1M facts * 10,000 bytes/per fact = 10GB-ish worth of text.) If you do hit this limit, you'll apparently hit it at cube "processing" time. Apparently it applies even to ROLAP dimensions. There may be some hacks to work around this. See [here](http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-analysis-services/very-large-dimensions-more-than-4gb-needed-for-store-file-33056.shtml). Note that Sql Server 2012 [may remove this 4GB limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg471589%28v=sql.110%29.aspx).

Forth, it seems that if long unique strings create a problem in SSAS, they do so at the level of in-memory representation. One potential problem (that I haven't looked into in detail) is that having these extra strings cached in memory will keep SSAS from keeping other important data structures in memory, and thus degrade performance. Another problem, suggested by the book [The Microsoft Data Warehouse Toolkit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470640383) (though I haven't yet found this claim elsewhere), is that SSAS does some expansive string padding on its in-memory data structures:

"The relational database stores variable length string columns ... However, other parts of the SQL Server toolset will fill these columns out to their full width. Notable, Integration Services and Analysis Services pad string columns with spaces as they are loaded into memory. Both Integration Services and Analysis Services love physical memory, so there's a cost to declaring string columns that are far wider than they need to be."

To conclude, so far storing my long string data in the cube seems convenient, and I haven't uncovered any reasons to expect disaster, so I'm giving it a try. I'll try to provide an update if things don't work out.

Answer (score 1):

You could store the values in a table relationaly and then create an integer surrogate key.

add the integer surrogate to your UDM and create a SSRS Drillthrough action

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms174526(v=SQL.90).aspx

that looks up the text field by the key value.

Comment: I was initially imagining that I could get SSAS to do something like this on my behalf simply by picking the right option from some config dropdown in Business Intelligence Dev Studio. (e.g. I was initially hoping something like this might happen if I created a RecordDescription dimension and marked it as ROLAP -- though now I think that's likely based on a misunderstanding of how ROLAP dimensions work.) But if it can't be as easy as changing a dropdown, then your proposal does sound clever.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a degenerate dimension, but hide it via SSAS until requested via a Drillthrough Action.

I can't guide you on the internal storage of strings for the AS engine, but as for storing them in SQL, I would make sure your varchar(MAX) column was at the end of your columns to speed up SQL engines scanning of those rows.

At 700,000 rows, with enough memory and disk I/O, you aren't taxing SQL much.

Comment: Does hiding the dim just amount to setting Visible=False (say, in Business Intelligence Dev Studio), or is there some more performance-oriented way to do it? I know at the attribute level there's a distinction between AttributeHierarchyVisible and AttributeHierarchyEnabled. The latter appears better for performance if you don't need to slice/dice on the attribute (as I don't in my case). Unfortunately AttributeHierarchyEnabled=False apparently means you [can't drillthrough](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/403083/drillthrough-improvements-to-make-usable-in-large-cubes).

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked through all the possibilities described and link to from it yet, but this thread from 2007 is on the same topic and seems pretty relevant:

http://www.sqldev.org/sql-server-analysis-services/discussion-about-how-to-create-a-fact-drillthrough-dimension-the-best-way-34857.shtml

One new possibility raised here is that, rather than treating text stored in the fact table as a degenerate *dimension*, you could potentially treat it as a text-valued (vs numeric-valued) *measure*. Initial googling suggests that SSAS might support this but there are some tricks to getting this right, e.g. you probably want to disable aggregation for that measure, you might need to do something non-standard to get the field to appear in a drillthrough, and it might require SSAS enterprise edition.